# Using Nested Projections in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

How to get expected output below where OrderProjection uses ItemProjection to render Items using Spring Data REST

GET /orders/1?projection=with_items

Projections :

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = Item.class)
public interface ItemProjection {
    String getName();
}

@Projection(name = "with_item", types = Order.class)
public interface OrderProjection {
    LocalDateTime getOrderedDate();
    Status getStatus();
    Set<ItemProjection> getItems(); // this is marshalling as Set<Item> (full Item graph)
}
```

Currently getting as output:

```
{
  "status" : "PAYMENT_EXPECTED",
  "orderedDate" : "2014-11-09T11:33:02.823",
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "Java Chip",
    "quantity" : 1,
    "milk" : "SEMI",
    "size" : "LARGE",
    "price" : {
      "currency" : "EUR",
      "value" : 4.20
    }
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders/1{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "restbucks:items" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders/1/items"
    },
    "curies" : [ {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/alps/{rel}",
      "name" : "restbucks",
      "templated" : true
    } ]
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "status" : "PAYMENT_EXPECTED",
  "orderedDate" : "2014-11-09T11:33:02.823",
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "Java Chip"
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders/1{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "restbucks:items" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders/1/items"
    },
    "curies" : [ {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/alps/{rel}",
      "name" : "restbucks",
      "templated" : true
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: WHOA! Didn't know I'm allowed to specify projection interfaces inside projections! Is it mentioned somewhere in the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into [DATAREST-394](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-394)  which has been fixed a few days a go and will be making it into 2.2.2 and 2.3 RC1. It's already available in the snapshots for said versions, feel free to give them a spin.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I used 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT for spring-data-rest-webmvc and this solves REST problem but with also 4.1.2.RELEASE for spring-framework-bom, I am finding that all my old URL associated with @RequestMapping from Spring MVC are giving 404 error

Comment: well 404 was happening due to missing Component Scan in MVC Context. < 2.2.1 Spring data rest Release, this however worked from Component Scan from Application Context

Comment: This issue reappears in 2.3.0.M1 for Spring Data Rest, I hope that is just because is milestone release.